# Why is time in Go printed differently in a struct?

Tags: datetime, go, struct

I'm just starting out with Go, and in the first program I wrote I printed out a struct, which also showed

```
{wall:0 ext:63533980800 loc:<nil>}
```

Being puzzled over what that was it seemed to be a type `time.Time()`, and a google search brought me to [this part of the Go source code](https://golang.org/src/time/time.go) in which the difference between the "wall clock" and the "monotonic clock" is explained in the comments.

So to test it in isolation I created a new minimalistic program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TheStruct struct {
    the_time time.Time
}

func main() {
    the_struct := TheStruct{time.Now()}
    fmt.Println(the_struct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", the_struct)
    fmt.Println(the_struct.the_time)
    fmt.Println()
    the_struct_2 := TheStruct{time.Unix(1505099248, 200)}
    fmt.Println(the_struct_2)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", the_struct_2)
    fmt.Println(the_struct_2.the_time)
}
```

which prints out the following:

```
{{13719544904843884912 534246 0x1140680}}
{the_time:{wall:13719544904843884912 ext:534246 loc:0x1140680}}
2017-09-11 05:08:11.35635032 +0200 CEST m=+0.000534246

{{200 63640696048 0x1140680}}
{the_time:{wall:200 ext:63640696048 loc:0x1140680}}
2017-09-11 05:07:28 +0200 CEST
```

So I wonder about two things here:

1. Why is the time if part of a struct printed as wall clock as compared to the more usual datetime notation when printed out separately (using `the_struct.the_time`)?
2. Is it a problem that the code in my other program prints out `<nil>` for the loc? How would I be able to solve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it's not printing the formatted time when in your struct is that String method is not invoked on the unexported fields (refer https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/):

> When printing a struct, fmt cannot and therefore does not invoke
>   formatting methods such as Error or String on unexported fields.

Changing your structure to export fields (capitalizing the first letter) makes it invoke the String method:

```
   package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type TheStruct struct {
    The_time time.Time
}

func main() {
    the_struct := TheStruct{time.Now()}
    fmt.Println(the_struct)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", the_struct)
    fmt.Println(the_struct.The_time)
    fmt.Println()
    the_struct_2 := TheStruct{time.Unix(1505099248, 200)}
    fmt.Println(the_struct_2)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", the_struct_2)
    fmt.Println(the_struct_2.The_time)
}
```

Output:

```
{2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000000}
{The_time:2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000000}
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000000

{2017-09-11 03:07:28.0000002 +0000 UTC}
{The_time:2017-09-11 03:07:28.0000002 +0000 UTC}
2017-09-11 03:07:28.0000002 +0000 UTC
```

On playground : https://play.golang.org/p/r0rQKBlpWc

Comment: When you have a nested struct, that solution doesn't work for me
https://go.dev/play/p/YddzXA9PQdP (here's an example in playground)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer covers the first part of your question quite well, so I will only cover the second part here.

To put it simply, no, a nil location is not a problem, as acording to the source code for `time.Time`, a nil location means UTC.

> ```
> // loc specifies the Location that should be used to
> // determine the minute, hour, month, day, and year
> // that correspond to this Time.
> // The nil location means UTC.
> // All UTC times are represented with loc==nil, never loc==&utcLoc.
> loc *Location
> ```