# Golang embedded `time.Time` printed over other fields

Tags: go

I'm a new starter in Go. Here is a problem that has been puzzling me.

In short, when I printed a `struct` with an anonymous field of the type `time.Time`, the output was similar to a `time.Time` variable printed alone. Neither braces nor other fields were displayed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Embedding struct {
    i       int
            time.Time
}
type NoEmbedding struct {
    i       int
    Present time.Time
}

func main() {

    // `embedding` and `noEmbedding` shared exactly the same content
    embedding := Embedding{
        1,
        time.Now(),
    }
    noEmbedding := NoEmbedding{
        1,
        time.Now(),
    }

    fmt.Println("embedding:\n", embedding)
    fmt.Println("no embedding:\n", noEmbedding)
}

/* output
embedding:
 2020-09-18 01:42:37.9201284 +0800 CST m=+0.011626601
no embedding:
 {1 2020-09-18 01:42:37.9201284 +0800 CST m=+0.011626601}
*/
```

The problem is essentially a further step into ["Why is time in Go printed differently in a struct?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147641/why-is-time-in-go-printed-differently-in-a-struct) I've gone over ["Embedding in GO"](http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-embedding.html) but yet to find any clues.

Answer (score 2):

`fmt.Println` will use the `String` method if one exists. When you embed a time value in a struct, the `String` method of `Time` is promoted to struct's `String` method. That's the reason why it prints differently.